# How can I fit a large column in latex?

Tags: tables, overleaf

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:


% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


% \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}


\begin{table}[]

\begin{tabular}{ll}


'Classes &
  Guidelines \\
Political Hate-speech &


  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A   tweet or phrase belongs to the 

‘‘Political Hate-speech’’ class assuming it   holds anyone or more of the following condition: \hline Abuse:   If a tweet contains any hate word about a political individual, political party, government or if   it targets the followers of a specific political party. For example, “Ap ka baap nawaz bhagora chor   h” translated in English as {[}Your father Nawaz is a truant and thief{]}.Some other offensive terms can be “youthia”   and “patwari” targeting the supporters of specific political parties.\end{tabular} \\    
Neutral &
  A tweet or phrase belongs to the ‘‘Neutral” class if   it does not hold any of the characteristics described for the Political   Hate-speech class, for example, ‘‘Wsa hi acha lgta ha mujha nawaz sharef”   translated in English as {[}I just like nawaz sharef{]}. \\
Offensive &  
  A tweet or phrase that belongs to the ‘‘Political   Hate-speech’’ class will further be classified as “Offensive”. If the tweet contains abusive words or   symbols promotes hostility, ignites anger, or incites harm to an   individual Political entity or a group of people that belong to a political   party or that support a political profile. For example, “Bhounktey rahhooooo   nawaz chor” translated in English as {[}Keep on barking nawaz thief{]}. \\
Sarcasm/ low-offensive &  
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A tweet or phrase that belongs to the ‘‘Political   Hate-speech’’ class will further be classified as “Sarcasm/ low-offensive”. If the tweet mocks and   convery contempt against a political individual, political party and   supporter of a specific political profile yet doesn’t contain explicit hate words.\\    \\ For example,” Bilkul   thek kaha ap nay nawaz Shareef nay boht investment ki h hmare adliya pay”   translated in English as {[} You are right, Nawaz shareef has invested a lot on   our judiciary system{]}.\end{tabular}  
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
```

[image: It appears like this in latex]

Comment: Please let us know which document class you employ.

Comment: See [page breaking - My table doesn't fit; what are my options? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options?noredirect=1&lq=1) first and see if it works.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report} @Mico this is the class

Comment: The code posted is messed up and doesn't even compile. Why are you using more tabulars within the tabular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of `tabularray` and `microtype` packages where for the second column is used `X[j]` column type which allow automatic line breaking and justifying of text:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} l X[j] @{}},
             row{2-Z}={rowsep=3pt}
             } 
Classes & Guidelines \\
    \midrule
Political hate-speech
    & A tweet or phrase belongs to the ``political hate-speech'' class if it satisfies one or more of the following conditions. \\
    & Abuse: If a tweet contains any hate word about a political individual, political party, government or if it targets the followers of a specific political party. For example, ``Ap ka baap nawaz bhagora chor h'' translated in English as [Your father Nawaz is a truant and thief]. Some other offensive terms can be ``youthia'' and ``patwari'' targeting the supporters of specific political parties. \\
Neutral
    & A tweet or phrase belongs to the ``neutral'' class if it does not hold any of the characteristics described for the political hate-speech class, for example, ``Wsa hi acha lgta ha mujha nawaz sharef'' translated in English as [I just like nawaz sharef]. \\
Offensive
    & A tweet or phrase that belongs to the ``political hate-speech'' class will further be classified as ``offensive'' if the tweet contains abusive words or symbols promotes hostility, ignites anger, or incites harm to an individual Political entity or a group of people that belong to a political party or that support a political profile. For example, ``Bhounktey rahhooooo nawaz chor'' translated in English as [Keep on barking nawaz thief]. \\
Sarcasm\slash low-offensive
    & A tweet or phrase that belongs to the ``political hate-speech'' class will further be classified as ``sarcasm\slash low-offensive''. If the tweet mocks and conveys contempt against a political individual, political party and supporter of a specific political profile yet doesn't contain explicit hate words. \\
    & For example, ``Bilkul thek kaha ap nay nawaz Shareef nay boht investment ki h hmare adliya pay'' translated in English as [You are right, Nawaz shareef has invested a lot in our judiciary system].
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `l` column type does not allow automatic line breaking. I would like to suggest you (a) get rid of the nested `tabular` environments and (b) employ a single `tabularx` environment, with the `X` column type in use for the second column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule and \addlinespace macros
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suspend full justification in L-type col.

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L @{}} % occupy full width of text block
Classes & Guidelines \\
\midrule
Political hate-speech 
& A tweet or phrase belongs to the ``political hate-speech'' class if it satisfies one or more of the following conditions. \\
\addlinespace
& Abuse: If a tweet contains any hate word about a political individual, political party, government or if it targets the followers of a specific political party. For example, ``Ap ka baap nawaz bhagora chor h'' translated in English as [Your father Nawaz is a truant and thief]. Some other offensive terms can be ``youthia'' and ``patwari'' targeting the supporters of specific political parties. \\ 
\addlinespace
Neutral 
& A tweet or phrase belongs to the ``neutral'' class if it does not hold any of the characteristics described for the political hate-speech class, for example, ``Wsa hi acha lgta ha mujha nawaz sharef'' translated in English as [I just like nawaz sharef]. \\
\addlinespace
Offensive 
& A tweet or phrase that belongs to the ``political hate-speech'' class will further be classified as ``offensive'' if the tweet contains abusive words or symbols promotes hostility, ignites anger, or incites harm to an individual Political entity or a group of people that belong to a political party or that support a political profile. For example, ``Bhounktey rahhooooo nawaz chor'' translated in English as [Keep on barking nawaz thief]. \\
\addlinespace
Sarcasm\slash low-offensive 
& A tweet or phrase that belongs to the ``political hate-speech'' class will further be classified as ``sarcasm\slash low-offensive''. If the tweet mocks and conveys contempt against a political individual, political party and supporter of a specific political profile yet doesn't contain explicit hate words. \\ 
\addlinespace
& For example, ``Bilkul thek kaha ap nay nawaz Shareef nay boht investment ki h hmare adliya pay'' translated in English as [You are right, Nawaz shareef has invested a lot in our judiciary system]. 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering how can i remove "Abuse" as a new row? because it isn't one its part of the text In front of Political hate-speech. When i do remove it the whole table falls apart.

Comment: @SamiaAziz - I must confess I didn't understand the code you posted around the "abuse" item. Does it belong in the right-hand column, along with the explanatory sentence(s)? Please clarify.

Comment: I apologize for the messed up code. Yes it belongs to right hand column first row.

Comment: @SamiaAziz - Then just change `Abuse & If a tweet` to `& Abuse: If a tweet` and rerun LaTeX.

Comment: It worked, thanks :)

Comment: @SamiaAziz - You're most welcome. Please also see the update code and screenshot I just posted.

Comment: I saw that, Got it